# What to do when front lawn grasses are becoming sparse?

Tags: lawn, grass

The front lawn areas to the right of the mailbox are becoming sparse with grasses. Is there a fix to make them grow dense again like the lawn in the top left of the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That will depend why they are sparse.

Driveway runoff can be bad for grass, depending what is on the driveway to wash off into the grass. If you use ice-melt (salt, etc.) in the winter that's one bad thing. If your car leaks fluids that's another.

The picture seems to show a fairly shady situation, which grass is not overly fond of, in general. Trimming trees may help. Choosing more shade tolerant "short green plants" is another option.

If the lawn on that side of the path was planted with a different type of grass than the lawn on the other side, replanting or overseeding it may help if the new seed is more suited to the situation.